# User session not maintained in IE10 for Drupal

Tags: internet-explorer, session, drupal

In my drupal site,after logging in certain menu links when opened in new tab are not maintaining session.This issue is existing in IE 10 only.Can anyone faced this issue with drupal site in IE10.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to test this myself, but I would recommend you to visit the Drupal site and search the core issue list to see if anyone else has reported this. I just did a quick general search, but could not find anything. ([Drupal Core issues](http://drupal.org/project/issues/drupal) right here)

Also, go through your settings to see if there's an oddball there. If not, you can always create a new issue on Drupal.org and address your problem.